# My app crashes suddenly

Tags: android-studio

I am developing an android application. Suddenly, when I included a blank fragment, the application crashed. Before adding the fragment application worked without any problem. So it is clear that the fragment caused for the crash. So I want to get to know how to solve this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: You should post the error itself and the code that caused it, please. Or look at the Android documentation on debugging

Comment: We still expect you to either provide a [mcve] or search and research how to diagnose the issue before posting here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add breakpoints to your program and then run it in debug mode which should show you the line of code causing the crash.

Comment: How to add a break point?

Comment: It depends on the IDE you are using. This is really for you to research yourself.